# Why was AppWidgetProvider.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged called on API 15?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-appwidget

I found this error in logcat after witnessing an AppWidget crash:

> 10-04 12:46:17.315: I/dalvikvm(13791): Could not find method android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged, referenced from method com.appkey.widget.MyAppWidgetProvider.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged

While I do have an `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged` method, my code does not call it, and I thought the system would only call it from API level 16 or above (per the SDK docs).  This error occurred on a Samsung Galaxy S2 Epic (SPH-D710) running android 4.0.4 @ API level 15.

```
public class MyAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @TargetApi(16)
    @Override
    public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions) {
        super.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, newOptions);
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That log line seems to be just informational (notice the "I" prefix) from dalvik when loading your class. It is not an error and should not be the cause of your crash.

I believe if you comment out that method, it is likely that your crash would still happen.

Comment: Maybe crash was a bit harsh.  The widget appeared to be reloaded around the time of this message, resetting all the state variables similar to a launcher restart... but I don't have proof of a restart and this scenario has not been easy to reproduce.  I'll follow up with more detail next time I observe it.  Thanks!

Comment: You can check to see whether that line is still printed out even under normal operation (without any crash/reload). From my understanding, it will always be printed the first time your class get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

That's just a class-loading error. When the DalvikVM loads your class it doesn't find the reference to noted method, so it issues a warning.